# Subscript equivalent of ' for \prime?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

I am working through the TeXbook and I came across the section (pg. 130) where `'` and `\prime` are discussed. Knuth mentions that TeX treats `\prime` as a large symbol that appears only in superscripts instead of making it a smaller symbol that has already been shifted up into the superscript position. Part of the reason is because some authors actually use `\prime` in the subscript position.

I know `$y'_1+y''_2$` yields a typographical output equivalent to that of `$y^\prime_1+y^{\prime\prime}_2$`, but I am wondering if there is an equivalent to `'` for putting the `\prime` into the subscript position.

For example, `$h'$` is typographically equivalent to `$h^\prime$`, but is `$h_\prime$` equivalent to any "quicker" expression (i.e., involving an apostrophe or something similar)? I tried `$h_'$`, but this produces an error; then I tried `$h_{'}$`, but I realized this is equivalent to typing `$h_{{}^\prime}$`.

Basically, is there a character `X` where `$hX$` and `$h_\prime$` are equivalent?

Comment: You can define it in a newcommand

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just mimic what the kernel does for `\prime`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\active@math@sprime{_\bgroup\sprim@s}
{\catcode`\`=\active \global\let`\active@math@sprime}
\def\sprim@s{%
  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\spr@m@s}
\def\spr@m@s{%
  \ifx`\@let@token
    \expandafter\spr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx_\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\spr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\spr@@@s#1{\sprim@s}
\def\spr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
\mathcode`\`="8000
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal use: `test'.

Math: $h`$ and $h``$ and also $h`_{1}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does this do? First of all, a backquote in math mode is dealt with as if it were an active character, because of `` \mathcode`\`="8000 ``; TeX will look for a definition of `` ` `` as active character, which is `\active@math@sprime`.

When it's found first in a possible sequence of backquotes, TeX expands `\active@math@sprime`, so doing `_\bgroup\sprim@s`. This starts a subscript, exploiting the fact that `_\bgroup<tokens>\egroup` is legal syntax. Now `\sprim@s` is expanded, which typesets `\prime` and does

```
\futurelet\@let@token\spr@m@s
```

This looks at the following token, stores it into `\@let@token` without removing it from the input stream and executes `\spr@m@s`.

This macro does some tests:

1. if `\@let@token` is a backquote, the `\else...\fi` part is removed by `\expandafter` and `\spr@@@s` is executed;
2. if `\@let@token` is `_` the `\else...\fi\fi` part is removed by the triple `\expandafter` and `\spr@@@t` is executed;
3. none of the above: `\egroup` is executed which will close the subscript.

Now let's look at `\spr@m@s`: it is defined just to remove the next token (which is a backquote) and does `\sprim@s` again. This is how ``` $h``$ ``` becomes `$h_\bgroup\prime\prime\egroup$`.

The macro `\spr@@@t` has two arguments: the first is `_` which is simply gobbled and the second is the intended subscript, which is closed by `\egroup` that balances the initial `\bgroup`. This is how `` $h`_{1}$ `` becomes `$h_\bgroup\prime 1\egroup`.

Comment: Wow I was actually thinking of trying to do just that, but I had no idea of how to do it. Somehow I stumbled across your `ensuremath` campaign. Don't know what all that is about but I hope you got somewhere with it. I also thought about making a new command, but is there a way to make a new command that only applies when used in math mode (or should I ask this as a separate question)?

Comment: I should probably add that I realize that is what you *just* did, but it looks quite a bit more complicated than something basic like what I am thinking about.

Comment: Hey! I was just working on it! :(

Comment: @yo' Why the sad face? By all means, please post what you have! I just felt like egreg really did answer the question, which he did...

Comment: @induktio It would be simpler if you just need one subscript prime not combined with other subscripts. But a double prime requires that approach. It's exactly the same process by which `'` is turned into prime: change the backquotes that don't immediately follow `\catcode` or `\mathcode` into `'`, all `_` into `^` and all `\sp...` into `\p...`: it will be the copy of the macros for `'`.

Comment: @induktio It doesn't make sense to provide duplicate answers.

Comment: @egreg what would be difference between this approach and \newcommand{\h`}[0]{h_\prime} ?

Comment: @phollox Simple: this one works, what you're proposing doesn't. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Amazing response. Clear and concise. Sir, you're my hero. What's the emoticon for "ashamed"?

Comment: @phollox Don't be ashamed: everybody needs to go through the stage where everything seems easy. ;-) Then we learn how to do things properly, because we understand better how TeX works.